# Can't connect nodes in shading

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I am using blender 2.82, 2.83, and 2.90 they all have same problem with nodes I can't connect the nodes in them..at first it was working..then due to no reason blender says unsupported graphics card. After fixing that nodes issue came. So I think it has to do something with it

Comment: is your graphics card, in fact, unsupported by blender?

Comment: Well at first it was going all well I can connect the nodes of shading etc. But few days later it said unsupported graphics so I wanted a tutorial on YouTube and I fix it. After fixing that shading nodes problem came.